# android services

Tags: android

I am creating an app which needs to retrieve a textfile from a webserver.

I have the manual retrieving done, just that I am thinking of adding a service to make the service check for the textfile like every 5 minutes and then send a notification to the user when a textfile is detected.

Is it ok to use a service here or do I have to use other methods?

Because the service will be kept running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great use of a service.  Just make sure to allow the user to enable or disable service component.  Also, try to shut it down when its not necessary (when the user cannot react to it).

Comment: have done the service which would allow the user to start stop the service and added a timer

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing this is setting a repeating alarm using `AlarmManager`, a `PendingIntent` and a `BroadcastReceiver` as well as a `Service`.  That way you don't have the service running all the time.

So the `AlarmManager` fires off the `PendingIntent` which is then picked up by the `BroadcastReceiver` which then starts your `Service` to perform the task in the background using a `Thread` or `AsyncTask` etc.  Also look at `IntentService` which runs a `Looper` to process an `Intent` and then shuts itself down.

Comment: so sorry dont really understand some of the parts any place i can have a better read? other than google developers

Comment: I have a book named Professional Android 2 Application Development by Wrox which covers it all but I'm sure you can find tutorials for free if you search on Android Repeating Alarms Service.